# Stack overflow when updating an embedded JavaFX TableView from Swing elements

Tags: java, swing, exception, javafx, focus

In JavaFX 2.2:

Is there a way to cleanly transfer focus to a Swing component from an embedded JavaFX component, and vice-versa?

Currently, the only (simple) way I found to transfer focus to the embedded JavaFX component is to call requestFocusInWindow() on the host JFXPanel. Focus then gets "magically" transferred to the JavaFX (TextArea). The problem is, when the JavaFX item in focus loses it to a Swing component, a stack overflow occurs. Checking the stack trace shows the JavaFX CSS processing running infinitely. Snippet of which:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.sun.t2k.LogicalFont.getCanonicalFamilyName(LogicalFont.java:55)
at com.sun.t2k.LogicalFont.getLogicalFont(LogicalFont.java:80)
at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.createFont(T2KFontFactory.java:338)
at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.font(PrismFontLoader.java:349)
at javafx.scene.text.Font.font(Font.java:143)
at javafx.scene.text.Font.font(Font.java:160)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.lookupFont(StyleHelper.java:2110)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.lookup(StyleHelper.java:1017)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:863)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7418)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Node.java:7363)
at javafx.scene.control.Labeled$6.invalidated(Labeled.java:323)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.applyStyle(StyleableObjectProperty.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:900)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7418)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Node.java:7363)
at javafx.scene.control.Labeled$6.invalidated(Labeled.java:323)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.applyStyle(StyleableObjectProperty.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:900)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7418)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Node.java:7363)
at javafx.scene.control.Labeled$6.invalidated(Labeled.java:323)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.applyStyle(StyleableObjectProperty.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:900)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7418)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Node.java:7363)
at javafx.scene.control.Labeled$6.invalidated(Labeled.java:323)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.applyStyle(StyleableObjectProperty.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:900)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7418)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Node.java:7363)
at javafx.scene.control.Labeled$6.invalidated(Labeled.java:323)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.applyStyle(StyleableObjectProperty.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:900)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7418)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Node.java:7363)
at javafx.scene.control.Labeled$6.invalidated(Labeled.java:323)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:129)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:163)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.set(StyleableObjectProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableObjectProperty.applyStyle(StyleableObjectProperty.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:900)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7418)
at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Node.java:7363)
```

IIRC, there's a ticket opened in JIRA regarding focus issues between the Swing and JavaFX threads, but I was hoping if someone here is aware of a workaround.

Edit: Turns out it wasn't simply a problem with focus between JavaFX and Swing, but with the interaction between their threads. Looking back when I first posted this, it lacked sufficient detail as to what I wanted to do.

I have a TableView backed by an **ObservableList** of type **Map**. I want its contents changed when a Swing component receives focus. The update process is properly pushed to the JavaFX thread via **Platform.runLater()**. I got it working, but it suddenly started spitting out a stack overflow.

I recently updated to Java 7u71, and thought there was an introduced bug with regard to component focus between Swing and JavaFX, which led to the original title of this question **"Transferring focus from embedded JavaFX to Swing"**. I was able to find the cause of the problem, and posted the answer below.

Comment: *"Snippet of which:"*  This 'snippet' does not include the (very useful) cause of the exception!

Comment: Sorry about that Andrew, as I've mentioned, it's goes on and on infinitely, dumping this stack trace over and over. I went over what Eclipse displays, trying to look for the root cause, but it's just this, I'm afraid. The application doesn't crash, but the JavaFX control becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to dig around a bit more to find the answer, though not deep enough to find out the root cause.

I implemented a customized TableCell (TextFieldTableCell), overriding **updateItem()** to set the style of the cell. I found that even when the update process for the backing ObservableList was passed to the JavaFX thread via **Platform.runLater()**, the stack overflow was caused by calls to updateItem(), whenever the table data was changed. Passing the style setting to the JavaFX thread, did the trick, like so:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(String value, final boolean isEmpty) {
    super.updateItem(value, isEmpty);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!isEmpty) {
                    setStyle("-fx-font-weight:bold; -fx-font-size:10");
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not really recommended, the super.updateItem call or other code observing the list might do something which requires it to be on the JavaFX application thread.  The better solution is to ensure that your ObservableList is not modified off the JavaFX application thread (e.g. if you are not on the JavaFX application thread, surround all updates to the ObservableList with a Platform.runLater call).

Comment: thanks JewelSea, sorry for only seeing this now. this component is a very simple one, and purely JFX, though it is embedded in a JFXPanel, which I think is what's causing the exception. I was careful to do things as you described, but I the issue still kept occurring. The only way I found, at least in JFX 2.2, was to do this workaround.